# Spring Validator error in Jdk 1.8

Tags: spring, java-8, spring-validator

We were using JDK 1.6 32 bit and trying to check few things in JDK 1.8 32 bit. We have a form validator whose class implements spring-context-3.0.7 validate method. springmodules-validation 0.4 version is also used. We have a date calendar object which we are trying to check if empty. In JDK 1.8 32 bit, this gives error even though it is filled/not empty. Would anyone know if it is not supported in JDK 1.8? Do I need a higher spring version?

This code gives an error. Joda DateTime is being used. JDK 1.8 32 bit gives error on validate method even though the date is not empty.

```
import org.joda.time.LocalDate;  
import org.springframework.validation.Errors;  
import org.springframework.validation.ValidationUtils;  
import org.springframework.validation.Validator;  

public class ChangeValidator implements Validator {
    public boolean supports(Class<?> clazz) {
        return (clazz.equals(VO.class));
    }
public void validate(Object object, Errors errors) {
    VO cvo= (VO) object;
    if ("hello".equals(cvo.getAction())) {  
        ValidationUtils.rejectIfEmpty(errors,  
            "checkInDate","CheckInDate.EMPTY",  
            "Please enter a valid checkin date");  
        ValidationUtils.rejectIfEmpty(errors,  
            "checkOutDate","CheckOutDate.EMPTY",  
            "Please enter a valid checkout date");  
   }}
```

Comment: Share whole error stack trace

Comment: please post code. Thanks.

Comment: Added the code.

Comment: In addition to the stack trace, please label lines in your code that the trace is pointing to.

Comment: There is no exception and it is just the error shown when we do 1.8. The error is shown for checkInDate (DateTime field)    
        ValidationUtils.rejectIfEmpty(errors,  
            "checkInDate","CheckInDate.EMPTY",  
            "Please enter a valid checkin date");